# Replace characters in preprocessor definition

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I have a definition which includes a path (with no escape sequence) like this one:

```
// Incorrect
#define PATH "c:\blah\blah\file.cfg"
```

I would rather like it as this:

```
// Corrected
#define PATH "c:\\blah\\blah\\file.cfg"
```

Though unfortunately I can not modify the macro definition (actually the script that generates the source that includes the macro...), except for adding prefixes. Now I need to open the file given in this path. I tried c++11 raw string literals like this:

```
// Modified definition
#define PATH R"c:\blah\blah\file.cfg"
std::ifstream(PATH); // error: unrecognised escape sequence
```

Now the question is how to replace all `\` using a macro?

Notes (if does matter):
Compiler: MSVC 14.0 
OS: Windows 7

Comment: \blah is actually \b followed by lah. Which is entirely a different character. There is no way of going from that to \\

Comment: If you have any control of your build system at all, it may be easier to just post-process the output of your code-gen script, before the compiler is run.

Comment: Correcting the script would be the best solution, and if this is really not possible, postprocessing is the next best solution IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for raw string that you generated is NOT correct.

Here's the correct one:

```
#define PATH R"(c:\blah\blah\file.cfg)"
```

Check the `(6)` syntax format at CPP reference:

> prefix(optional) R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter" (6)

See: [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Example: http://ideone.com/OZggmK

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the preprocessor's stringify-operator `#`, which does not only encapsulate the parameter in double quotes but also escapes "ordinary" backslashes in the string. Then - at runtime - cut off the extra double quotes introduced by the stringify.

So the idea is the following:

1. somehow stringify `PATH` such that `"c:\blah\blah\file.cfg"` becomes
   `"\"c:\\blah\\blah\\file.cfg\""`. Note that the string itself
   contains double quotes as the first and the last character then.
2. at runtime, use `substr` to cut the value between the (unwanted)
   double quotes

A bit tricky is to stringify a value that is itself provided as a macro. To do that, you can use a macro with variadic arguments (as these get expanded).
So the complete code would look as follows:

```
#define PATH "c:\blah\blah\file.cfg"

#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(A) #A
#define STRINGIFY(...) STRINGIFY_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NORMALIZEPATH(P) string(STRINGIFY(P)).substr(1,strlen(STRINGIFY(P))-2)

int main() {

    string filename =  NORMALIZEPATH(PATH);
    cout << "filename: " << filename << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
filename: c:\blah\blah\file.cfg
```